# Jmeter test error : URI does not specify a valid host name

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I have configured  Jmeter  in Jenkins pipeline but when the stage runs it appears as if the tests are not executing **as expected** and in the console output I can see an error
***Non HTTP response message: URI does not specify a valid host name: http:/http:10.XXX.XXX.XXX:32518/account?field4=3025202645050&field7=generic01&field10=abc098*** . The URL is being intepreted incorrectly as it has http **appearing twice**.

This is part of the Jenkins pipeline :

```
pipeline {
agent any
triggers {
    githubPush()
}
environment { 
.......
   REPOSITORY_URI = "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}"
}
    stages {
......
.......
      stage ("UnitTest Report") {
                 steps{               
                         publishHTML target: [
          allowMissing: false,
          alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
          keepAll: true,
          reportDir: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FlexToEcocash_main/IntegrationTests/BuildReports/Coverage',
          reportFiles: 'index.html',
          reportName: 'Code Coverage'
          ]
                   archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'IntegrationTests/BuildReports/Coverage/*.*'
                   }
             }
                stage ("Perfomance Test") {
                steps {
                         build job: 'EcoToFlexPerfomanceTests'     
                }
             }
    }
    
    }
```

The stage Perfomance Test triggers a Freestyle Job named **EcoToFlexPerfomanceTests** and this will be the one that runs Jmeter tests.

Part of the console output :
[image: JmeterConsole]

Looking at the Performance Test Reports I am not sure if they are also showing the data correctly, they seem not populated as of now:

[image: Jreports]

**Environment:
Debian 10 Buster
.Net 5 API running on k0s**

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler in your script:

[image]

It should look like:

```
http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:32518/account......
```

so use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to see all [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with their values and correct the URL of the sampler and the problem should go away.